# If-statement scoped variables

Tags: scala

Often times I have a desire to create variables scoped to an if statement.  Some computations only relate to a particular 'if' statement - to pollute the outer scope with temporary variables smells bad.

What I would like to do:

```
val data = (whatever)

if (val x = data*2+5.4345/2.45; val y = data/128.4; x*y < 10) 
  x * y
else
  x * 2

println(x) //ERROR!
```

One alternative is rather messy:

```
val data = (whatever)

if (data*2+5.4345/2.45*data/128.4 < 10) 
  data*2+5.4345/2.45*data/128.4
else
  data*2+5.4345/2.45 * 2
```

The obvious alternative I'm trying to avoid:

```
val data = (whatever)
val x = data*2+5.4345/2.45
val y = data/128.4

if (x*y < 10) 
  x*y
else
  x * 2

println(x) //OK
```

Is something like this possible in Scala?  Is there a decent workaround? If not, what other languages support an idea like this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since `if` in Scala is an expression, i.e. it returns a value, normally you'd be setting some value to the result of your `if` expression. So your third alternative is just fine: put it in a code block, i.e.

```
val data = (whatever)
val myValue = {
  val x = data*2+5.4345/2.45
  val y = data/128.4

  if (x*y < 10) 
    x*y
  else
    x * 2
}
```

None of the `val`s declared within the block are available outside it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a pattern match:

```
val data = 123

val (result, x) = (data*2+5.4345/2.45, data/128.4) match {
  case (x, y) if x * y < 10 => (x * y, x)
  case (x, _)               => (x * 2, x)
}

println(x)
```

`result` contains the result of `x * y` or `x * 2`, depending on which computation ran, and `x` contains the value of `data*2+5.4345/2.45` as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a scope for it...

```
{
  val x = data*2+5.4345/2.45
  val y = data/128.4;
  if ( x*y < 10) 
    x * y
  else
    x * 2
}
```

Or, to make it clearer,

```
locally {
  val x = data*2+5.4345/2.45
  val y = data/128.4;
  if ( x*y < 10) 
    x * y
  else
    x * 2
}
```