# Scala shorthand for declaring and returning a variable

Tags: scala, shorthand

Just for curiosity is there a shorthand for

```
test = "test"
test
```

I tried something like that

```
(test = "test")
```

or

```
//if ((test = "test") != null) test
if (test = "test") test
```

//edit: I have to set test variable before I return it.

Comment: Why are you making a `var`? Can you give any larger examples of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: The shorthand for this code is just `"test"` provided that you avoid an explicit return statement.

Comment: You don't normally need to `return` in scala, and idiomatically you should avoid using it. Just have `"test"` be the last statement of your function.

Comment: I have to set the variable before I return it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8845459/3641692 it is not possible

I have to do it on multiple lines:

```
var test: String = null

def setter(t:String): String = {
  test = t
  test
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your example doesn't make much sense. If you're inside some scope, vars/vals/defs inside that scope are not accessible from outside that scope - so there's no need for this. You'd just return the value (using implicit return).

`"test"`